# AppDomain 404 Error SharePoint 2016 on-premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, 2016, 404, sharepoint-store

I have 2 different domains setup. One for sharepoint and another for apps.

The appdomain was setup using the below guide.
http://jbarkes.blogspot.com/2013/10/create-isolated-app-domain-in.html

I am currently experiencing a 404 error. There is currently a web application setup for port 80 which doesn't have a header is IIS. I don't wish to delete this and lose the site I have already created. I can ping the ip address for the appdomain but cannot ping it by its name. I can ping the appdomain by name from another computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this? How can I get the apps to work in sharepoint?

[image: 404 Error]

If I change the Appdomain to the IP instead of the name, I get a "This page can't be displayed" error, make sure http://*.IP is correct

Comment: Are you getting 404 for the WA or the app? If you ping the appdomain on the server, will you get the correct ip? If not, you can add in the DNS host record for "informatrix" to point to a specific ip for starters and see if that will resolve.

Comment: It's for any apps from the apps store. If I ping the host name, no results but pinging the IP works. If I ping the name from another pc, I get the ip. Do you know how to point a DNS host record to a specific IP?

Comment: Is it a custom domain that you bought somewhere or you are setting up a test/dev env and the domain "exists" only on your server?  If only on the server then go to your DNS, right-click on the app domain, add record (Host=A), there is a field for IP address. Enter the IP for the server. Do ipconfig /flushdns, clear your browser and see if the domain resolves or pings.

Comment: @grisha it's a domain in the internal network for dev/testing.

Comment: @grisha adding the host file has allow me to ping the app domain from the sharepoint server. Now I'm just getting a "page can't be displayed" error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Close the browser/clear the cache. Is it still cannot be found? Do you have any page that should be displayed? 2. Have you configured CA>Apps>App urls? Can u add now an app from the Store? (If you could it means at least some settings are ok :) ) Does the store app open?

Comment: @grisha After clearing cache, the page still cannot be found. The App url is configure in CA. I can add apps from the store. Could this have anthing to do with using 2 adapters in the vm? One is bridged and the other is for the vm1host network with a static ip and dns configured. The bridge one uses another domain.

Comment: @grisha got the appdomain to work. added a host file (same as parent) with ip where dns is located and another host file with the name and ip of the sharepoint server.